# JSON decode array with preg_replace in PHP for Twitter tweet

Tags: php, json, regex

I have the following PHP code to create a Twitter timeline with clickable links:

```
   if ($this->tweets === null) {
        $this->tweets = self::$connection->get($type, ['count' => $count, "exclude_replies" => $er, "tweet_mode" => 'extended', "screen_name" => $screenname]);
        $this->tweets = json_decode(json_encode($this->tweets), true);
        $twitterCache->set($cachename, $this->tweets, option('twit.cachelife'));
    }

   public function setLinks($source) {
    array_walk_recursive(
      $source,
        function (&$value, $key) {
          if (in_array($key, array('url','text','full_text','expanded_url','description','display_url'), true ) ) {
            if (!is_array($value)) {
              $value = $this->linkify($value);
            }
          }
        }
      );
    return $source;
  }


   public function linkify($value, $protocols = array('http', 'https', 'twitter', 'mail'), array $attributes = array('target' => '_blank'))
    {
    // Link attributes
    $attr = '';
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $val) {
        $attr = ' ' . $key . '="' . htmlentities($val) . '"';
    }

    $links = array();

    // Extract existing links and tags
    $value = preg_replace_callback('~(<a .*?>.*?</a>|<.*?>)~i', function ($match) use (&$links) { return '<' . array_push($links, $match[1]) . '>'; }, $value);

    // Extract text links for each protocol
    foreach ((array)$protocols as $protocol) {
        switch ($protocol) {
            case 'http':
            case 'https':   $value = preg_replace_callback('~(?:(https?)://([^\s<]+)|(www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])~i', function ($match) use ($protocol, &$links, $attr) { if ($match[1]) $protocol = $match[1]; $link = $match[2] ?: $match[3]; return '<' . array_push($links, "<a $attr href=\"$protocol://$link\">$link</a>") . '>'; }, $value); break;
            case 'mail':    $value = preg_replace_callback('~([^\s<]+?@[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+)(?<![\.,:])~', function ($match) use (&$links, $attr) { return '<' . array_push($links, "<a $attr href=\"mailto:{$match[1]}\">{$match[1]}</a>") . '>'; }, $value); break;
            case 'twitter': $value = preg_replace_callback('~(?<!\w)[@#](\w++)~', function ($match) use (&$links, $attr) { return '<' . array_push($links, "<a $attr href=\"https://twitter.com/" . ($match[0][0] == '@' ? '' : 'search/%23') . $match[1]  . "\">{$match[0]}</a>") . '>'; }, $value); break;
            default:        $value = preg_replace_callback('~' . preg_quote($protocol, '~') . '://([^\s<]+?)(?<![\.,:])~i', function ($match) use ($protocol, &$links, $attr) { return '<' . array_push($links, "<a $attr href=\"$protocol://{$match[1]}\">{$match[1]}</a>") . '>'; }, $value); break;
        }
    }

    // Insert all link
    return preg_replace_callback('/<(\d+)>/', function ($match) use (&$links) { return $links[$match[1] - 1]; }, $value);
    }
```

The written text decodes correctly to readable content, even for umlauts or other non English characters but the tags (links) break with every special character and I would like to know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use addslashes() function for escaping special characters

Comment: and stripcslashes after that

Comment: Can you show that in a code snippet please?